# Is it possible to instantiate a new WC_Cart?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to use a different plugin's functionality without letting it run normally. It has a function that uses a WC_Cart object, and I want to give it a cart that is completely spoofed. Absolutely not the standard WC()->cart.

I do not want to modify any plugins, and I want to keep my work inside the functions.php file.

Is it possible to make a new WC_Cart like this? How exactly can I do that?

Do I have to import the plugin file that contains the WC_Cart class? Or is it possible to access it without having to do that?

Comment: which plugin do you speak about ? how is instanciated this object WC_Cart in the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I was in the incorrect namespace. A new woocommerce cart can be instantiated by

```
$cart = new WC_Cart();
```

assuming you're in the same namespace as the cart, but if you are in a different namespace and suffering the problem I had with my original question, you would change it to:

```
$cart = new /WC_Cart();
```

As the / means to check the standard namespace, the same namespace the WC_Cart was declared in.